# Safari Search History for Discord username

Tags: macos, safari, search

I had an old friend on Discord and I'm attempting to find their username. I had the account but eventually got locked out of it forever, and I ended up deleting it.

Now, I want to add this person back. I found their username in my search history (looked like “Discord | @username…) but I clicked open the link and it just brought me to the Discord sign in. Now it just says “Discord…” without their username because I opened the log in not the direct messages, but it is still the same link.

I’m on macOS Sonoma and keep it current on general releases.

Is there anyway to access this old link from history before the URL was rewritten?

Comment: The URL wasn't re-written, the title was. The URL never went to anywhere special. It's unlikely you'll be able to find it without doing a full restore (via Time Machine, etc.) of your safari data files

Comment: Is it very hard to do? Would you reccomend it?

Comment: I'm not sure, search for restoring your Safari history with Time Machine and see if you find any results